# React Native, Image Slider Box with text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native and I installed `react-native-image-slider-box` but I also want that when image slide title of that image will also change like user slide image so title of that image will also change. I change code of react-native-image-slider-box package but it's not working.
Below is that Code

```
 _renderItem({ item, index }) {
    const {
      ImageComponent,
      ImageComponentStyle = {},
      sliderBoxHeight,
      disableOnPress,
      resizeMethod,
      resizeMode,
      imageLoadingColor = "#E91E63"
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          position: "relative",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
      >
        <Text style={[style.fontSize30Semi, {marginRight: moderateScale(100)}]}>
          {this.props.title}
        </Text> //that's the code I added in react-native-image-slider-box
          <ImageComponent
            style={[
              {
                width: '100%',
                height: moderateScaleVertical(350),
                marginVertical: moderateScaleVertical(10),
              },
              ImageComponentStyle
            ]}
            source={typeof item === "string" ? { uri: item } : item}
            resizeMethod={resizeMethod || "resize"}
            resizeMode={resizeMode || "cover"}
            onLoad={() => {}}
            onLoadStart={() => {}}
            onLoadEnd={() => {
              let t = this.state.loading;
              t[index] = true;
              this.setState({ loading: t });
            }}
            {...this.props}
          />
        {!this.state.loading[index] && (
          <ActivityIndicator
            size="large"
            color={imageLoadingColor}
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              alignSelf: "center"
            }}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Welcome.js

```
 state = {
    images: [imagePath.welcome1, imagePath.welcome2, imagePath.welcome3],
    desc: ['Hello', 'My'],
  };
  ...
  <SliderBox images={this.state.images} title={this.state.desc} />
```

That's my code where I trying to render different title for different image. Can anyone please help me and tell how can I do that??

Comment: The library doesnt support any text, do you want to place the text below the image slider ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library doenst support any texts, you can do something like below

```
 state = {
    images: [imagePath.welcome1, imagePath.welcome2, imagePath.welcome3],
    desc: ['Hello', 'My'],
    currentIndex:0
  };
  
      <Text>{this.state.desc[this.state.currentIndex]}</Text>
      <SliderBox images={this.state.images} title={this.state.desc} currentImageEmitter={i=>this.setState({currentIndex:i})}/>
```

The currentImageEmitter will send the index of the current image and you can use it to update the state and show the text based on the index.

Comment: still not updating text

Comment: @SaadAhmed didnt get you ?

Comment: currentImageEmitter this event was not updating state of currentIndex

Comment: Are you using the same code? maybe create a snack so that i can check the issue for you